# What should I do when flagging if I don't see the destination site in the list?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, off-topic

Sometimes I want to flag a question on Stack Overflow because it belongs to [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com) or [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com), but I don't see those sites on the list provided when you click on:

*It doesn't belong here* > *off topic*

I usually see:

- [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)
- [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)
- [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)
- [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)
- [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you flag, choose

- *it needs ♦ moderator attention* -> *other*

and explain why that question should migrate there?

Comment: So, if I want to flag it as off topic to a site that doesn't appear in the list, I have to tell why I think that?

Comment: @Oscar, flagging involve marking your flag as valid or invalid, I mean it effects your flag weight. So, if you just write "please migrate this question to site X", there is a chance that they will reject your flag.

Comment: @YOU I know that, but if 5 other users say the same, there is no chance they will reject it, do you know what I mean? I've flagged questions to migrate them to Programmers SE and they have been migrated because other users said the same...

Comment: @Oscar, if you suppose to do a feature-request to add "math" or "cs" site to off-topic list, there has been someone already requested before, and got declined as the reason "only 5 site available on the list"

Comment: @YOU Ok :) I just wanted to know what to do in that case

Comment: @OscarMederos: Please only do this for *VERY GOOD* reasons.  If it is sort-of on topic at SO and already has answers/upvotes, then don't bother.  If it is languishing in obscurity or is not a good fit for SO, please feel free.